# help cannot change inotify watch number because file cant be over written

Tags: backup, sudo, gedit, dropbox, inotify

so I'm trying to start using lsyncd for a more up to date backup system.

the problem that i have run into is that the directory that i have to backup contains more than 250,000 items and i would like to increase the watch size naturally to something like 300,000 watch items, a number that the architects in the office wont reach for a long time. so when i go to do that i access the watch plain text file via:

```
    sudo gedit /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

and change to 300,000. I hit save but even as `sudo` it wont let me save the darn file.
I have tried doing the same operation while the daemon is off then starting it, check it, still not changed.

the exact error that I get is:

```
Could not create a backup file while saving /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

so my question is how to effectively change that file's contents from 8192 to 300,000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this website has the answer in the comments about how to edit the file in question.

http://monodevelop.com/Inotify_watches_limit

so that you do not have to search for the comment on the site this is correct command that worked perfectly for me.

echo yourNumber | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches

for those of us who didnt know that much about inotify, pay attention to the number that you enter. the number that you enter must be a multiple of 2.

so because i had such a large amount of items to watch (257,048) i wanted to go to a number that was at least as high as 300,000 items being watched. the closest multiple of 2 was 285184, which was not enough for me. thus i multiplied by two to get 570368. so i will probably never have to touch that file again (yay).

enjoy a cup of ubuntu, cheers